# Python eval() changes UserDict type to dict

Tags: python

When using `eval()` to run a function with args the type of the argument is changed from `UserDict` to `dict`.

When it is called directly the type is correct.

Here is a small example:

```
from UserDict import UserDict


class MyDicet(UserDict):
    pass


def func(arg):
    print(arg.__class__.__name__)


arg = MyDicet()

args = {"arg": arg}
func(**args)
eval("func(**%s)" % args)
```

Output:

```
MyDicet
dict
```

Comment: The literal representation of a dict and a user dict is the same `{...}` so there's no way for `eval` to know that `{}` is a UserDict.

Comment: Check the result of `print(args)`